# Find repeating pattern in 2D list

Tags: list-manipulation, version-9

How it is possible to find repeating pattern and it horizontal shift in 2D list? The example list with repeating pattern could be generated using the following code:

```
p = {{1, 0, 2, 0, 1}, {2, 3, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1},
     {4, 1, 2, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 2, 3, 1}, {4, 1, 2, 0, 0}, {5, 1, 2, 3, 0}};

l = 50;

list = Table[{ConstantArray[0, l + 5 - i + Floor[4*i/(p // Length)] + 
      Mod[i, (p // Length)]], p[[1 + Mod[i, (p // Length)]]], 
     ConstantArray[0, 8 + i - Mod[i, (p // Length)]]} // Flatten, {i, 1, 50}];

ArrayPlot[list, ColorRules -> {1 -> Blue, 2 -> Black}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an undefined variable `l` in the OP. Below I use:

```
p = {{1, 0, 2, 0, 1}, {2, 3, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2, 0, 1}, {4, 1, 2, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 2, 3, 1}, {4, 1, 2, 0, 0}, {5, 1, 2, 3, 0}};
list = PadRight[Table[{ConstantArray[0, 50 + 5 - i + Floor[4*i/(p // Length)] + Mod[i, (p // Length)]], p[[1 + Mod[i, (p // Length)]]], ConstantArray[0, 8 + i - Mod[i, (p // Length)]]} // Flatten, {i, 1, 50}], {Automatic, 100}];
```

First use the uniform norm to fit the shift:

```
fit = FindFit[Position[Unitize[list], 1],
              a x + b, {a, b}, x, NormFunction -> (Norm[#, ∞] &)];
location[row_] = Rationalize[{a, b} /. fit].{row, 1}
```

> 422/7 - (3 row)/7

Unshift the list:

```
noShift = MapThread[RotateLeft, {list, Floor[location[Range[Length[list]]]]}];

period = Length[Last[FindTransientRepeat[noShift, 2]]]
```

> 7

```
pattern = With[{onePeriod = SparseArray[list[[;; period]]]},
  onePeriod[[All, Span @@ MinMax[onePeriod["AdjacencyLists"]]]]];

ArrayPlot[pattern, ColorRules -> {1 -> Blue, 2 -> Black}]
```

[image]

```
horiShift = -Coefficient[location[row], row] period
```

> 3

Comment: No FindTransientRepeat in Mathematica 9 ;(

Comment: What about horizontal shift of the pattern? In the example it is equal to 3.